# About phpmailer, and $mail->AddAddress

Tags: php, phpmailer

im looping through something that generates an email and I want it to send each unique item to a unique person.

I found, that when I use $mail->AddAddress, the next time it loops, It just adds the address, including all the recipients from the previous loops, and sends them all out.

How can I reset the address variable?

```
      loop(xtimes){

      [generate customer $message]

      $mail->Host       = "smut.blabla.com"; 
      $mail->port = 25;
      $mail->AddReplyTo('test@test.com', 'test name');
      $mail->AddAddress($currentEmployeeEmail);
      $mail->SetFrom('test@test.com', 'test name');
      $mail->Subject = "Your Daily Report, for $currentEmployee - $reportDate";
      $mail->MsgHTML($message);
      $mail->AddAttachment('logo_white.png'); 
      $mail->Send();
      }
```

Is there something equal to SetAddress?

Answer (score 3):

What if you create a new mailer at the beginning of the loop, like:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
```

If I remember, there's also a `ClearAddresses` method, like:

```
$mail->ClearAddresses();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$mail->ClearAllRecipients( )
```